# Chrome 20 websocket handshake

Tags: php, google-chrome, websocket

I'am using PHP Websocket server by  lemmingzshadow ([web](https://github.com/lemmingzshadow/php-websocket)). Everything worked just fine till now.

After update to chrome 20, if I want to do handshake with server it ends with this error

```
Error during WebSocket handshake: Sec-WebSocket-Protocol mismatch
```

Headers from chrome 20

```
GET /demo HTTP/1.1
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Host: gomokulive.eu:8001
Origin: http://www.gomokulive.eu
Sec-WebSocket-Key: s+AMQQu4Q10xH2AKy49byg==
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: x-webkit-deflate-frame
```

Headers sent back:

```
HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Sec-WebSocket-Accept: dMCVYKkF5VRrIouWFW7EYdvfD28=
Sec-WebSocket-Protocol: demo
```

I think problem is with "Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: x-webkit-deflate-frame" header from Chrome 20.

Any idea how to get it working again?

Comment: There appears to be a problem with Chrome 20 Websockets since yesterday's upgrade, primarily on the Windows platform... revert to the previous version if you can, or Google will almost certainly be issuing a patch pretty quickly because it prevents acces sto roaming profiles

Comment: I have game which runs on websockets, so it's nothing like "revert to previus version". If ws client cant connect users will see only error message :/ For now I went back to flash implementation https://github.com/gimite/web-socket-js

Comment: @MarkBaker any new information about this? bug or a feature? thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The server is violating the WebSocket protocol. It's likely that Chrome is just adhering to the standard more correctly in version 20 and that is revealing a bug in the server.

The problem is that the server is sending back a "Sec-WebSocket-Protocol" header in the response but this is only legal if the client sends the same header in the request. If the client does not send the Sec-WebSocket-Protocol then the server should omit the header in the response.

See the /subprotocol/ description on page 22 in [Section 4.2.2 of rfc6455](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-4.2.2)

Comment: It seems like you hit the point :) I will test it more carefully tomorow

Answer (score 3):

A quick fix for [php-websocket](https://github.com/lemmingzshadow/php-websocket) would be:

```
$response.= "Sec-WebSocket-Accept: " . $secAccept . "\r\n";
if (isset($headers['Sec-WebSocket-Protocol']))
{
    $response.= "Sec-WebSocket-Protocol: " . substr($path, 1) . "\r\n";
}
$response .= "\r\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

An EASY way to fix is add `Sec-WebSocket-Accept` information when do_handshake, code as below:

```
    list($resource,$host,$origin,$key) = $this->getheaders($buffer);

    $accept = base64_encode(SHA1($key."258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11", true));

    $upgrade  = "HTTP/1.1 101 Web Socket Protocol Handshake\r\n" .
            "Upgrade: WebSocket\r\n" .
            "Connection: Upgrade\r\n" .
            "WebSocket-Origin: {$origin}\r\n" .
            "WebSocket-Location: ws://{$host}{$resource}\r\n".
            "Sec-WebSocket-Accept: " . $accept . "\r\n\r\n";
    $this->handshakes[$socket_index] = true;

    socket_write($socket,$upgrade,strlen($upgrade));
```

where,

`$accept = base64_encode(SHA1($key."258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11", true));`

$key is `Sec-WebSocket-Key` got from $buffer, you can print_r($buffer) to have a look.

Hope this can solve your problem..

Comment: where does the 258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11 value come from?

Comment: I wonder it is fixed post, try it. I don't remember exactly, as it's year ago.